# Is there a way to move an item in a list to a folder in that list in Sharepoint 2007?

Tags: 2007

This is about a List not a Library.

Is there a way to move an item in a list to a folder in that list in Sharepoint 2007. I have a list with multiple folders. What I'm trying to do is move items from the root folder to another folder in the list.

I've seen an article about copying and pasting between two datasheet views in the UI, but that would probably change sime vital info I need to preserve, like Created By and Modified By.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need to set the ParentFolder property of the item. You have to use code to do that via webservices or object model code. I don't think there is an easier way to do it.

Comment: Thank you. I suspected as much. In Access I can look at the list and see that field, but I can't change it there. Unfortunately, I don't have access to the server end of things yet, but I'm chomping at the bit with the IT folks here to get such access.

Comment: Can you run javascript code? If so you can use the jQuery library and the SPServices library to update the items properties from client side code.

Comment: Yes, I use js all the time, as well as SPServices. Can you update the ParenbFolder property using SPServices?

Comment: I think so. You may check the SPServices site for comments on that. I think I have seen others do this.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Manage Content and Structure](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-server-help/work-with-site-content-and-structure-HA010131723.aspx#BM5) to move the item to the folder.